# SSRS: Formatting special guideline

Tags: reporting-services

in my chart I'd like to print one of the horizontal guidelines bold (eg. the 160-line)

[image: example]

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you already have that line on the chart and want to format it or do you want to know how to create such a line?

Comment: I have the lines in 40 steeps. I search for something like IIF(myInterval=160,True,False)

Comment: One common hack you could try only if you know there will be one repeat per max x value would be to draw a minor axis line for your value.